# Breaking an environment into multiple objects

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm completely new to Blender and wanted to gain some experience with the software. As my first project I decided to recreate an entrance to a underpass that's close to where I live.

The walls from the structure are mostly continuous so I'm not sure on how (or if) should I break them into multiple objects. I tried leaving it as a single giant object but I don't know if it would give problems when adding modifiers (as I'm looking forward to round the wall edges a bit).

[image: An entrance to a underpass rendered with Blender]

I also thought about breaking it down it like so:

[image: Same underpass as before, circled to show how I'd break it down]

But it still feels like the objects are too big, and since everything is a single scenario I don't know if it's really a good idea to break it down to multiple pieces. What should I do, and if there's no concrete answer, what are the pros and cons of each method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an advocate of breaking meshes up. There are numerous reasons that I feel this way:

1. Not many objects in real life are solid chunks.  Maybe concrete walls to a certain extent, but even those tend to have seams to allow for movement and expansion so they don't crack.  Seams will add realism.
2. When your object starts to get large and/or complex, the mesh topology can get weird in places.  For example, I would guess you have a lot of extra edges where the stairs connect with the walls.  Those edges wouldn't be needed if the stairs are separate.
3. It's *way* easier to UV/unwrap smaller, simpler objects than it is with large complex objects.  Similarly, it's a lot easier to assign materials to whole meshes rather than selecting individual faces.
4. Even as separate pieces you can still group the objects together in Blender so you can move them as a unit, so keeping them together doesn't really give you much of an advantage there.

That's mainly what I can think of off the top of my head.  I hope that's helpful!